# C# Unit Test to ensure every throw of exception has unique error code

Tags: c#, unit-testing, exception, mstest, error-code

## Background

I have a custom `Exception` called `ErrorCodeException`.

```
public class ErrorCodeException : Exception
{
    public ErrorCodeException(int errorCode, string message) : base(message)
    {
        ErrorCode = errorCode;
    }

    public int ErrorCode { get; }
}
```

I want to ensure that **every** place in the code I `throw` this exception, it has a `unique` error code.
Since we are using this to find the source of the error in the code, it cannot be randomly generated at run-time.
It must be hard-coded *AND* unique.

## Problem

The issue is that some programmers may forget to check if the error code is already used.
Alternatively they may have checked, but someone else took the same code in another branch, and then when both are merged together it is no longer unique.

## Question

Is there a way to write a **Unit Test** to search for *all* calls of `ErrorCodeException` and ensure every `errorCode` input is unique?

Comment: "since we are using this to find the source of the error" - isn't that what a stack trace is for? Sounds like you're making a new and complicated solution to an already solved problem.

Comment: You can use filename and line number to identify source location using `[CallerFilePath]` and `[CallerLineNumber]` and you can also get some other information like the version from the executable. Very easy to use, far less maintenance and more than adequate for most application. Often just the error message itself is unique enough to figure out the source of the error.

Comment: @mason We don't want the users to have access to information about the stack trace, and prefer to just have them send an error code when in need of support

Comment: @Phil1970 caller class/method name good idea, the line number is a bad idea, when a number of lines change over time, maintaining become not practical.

Comment: @Phil1970 I would like to use the error code, as that is what we have been doing thus far

Comment: @Tyler I assume you log the exceptions in your logger and analyze them afterwords to find the issue.

Comment: @MaythamFahmi Not impractical if you include the the build information with your apps (such as a git tag, version number, or commit hash) that readily identifies the source code it came from. Which you'd need to do anyways, since there's no guarantee your method names wouldn't change, or error numbers, or whatever other system used.

Comment: @MaythamFahmi sometimes they are logged, sometimes they are displayed directly to the user. I am more concerned with the ones displayed to the user. Since for those we really just want a simple error code that they can send us when they have an issue.

Comment: Is this a desktop app? Or a web app? Is it hosted on the clients infrastructure, or your own?

Comment: If you don't want to show the trace (or other similar technical information) to your user, then I would recommand you to provide a way to send an error report where the user would be able to provide an explaination of what they were doing.

Answer (score 0):

I could maybe see this type of test (though probably a bit too big to consider a unit test) being done with a custom script check.

Make a script to find and search for all constructor calls to `ErrorCodeException` in your source code. Read the first parameter to the constructor, and add it to a set, erroring if the element already exists.

However, this test would place some restrictions on future development. First, constructing a `ErrorCodeException` from a factory method or similar abstraction is now out of the question. Second, this assumes all your error codes are hardcoded at the constructor call. If you ever decide to calculate an error code with a function, the script will likely break.

Comment: Is there a way to write such a script directly in C#? I.e. using `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting`

Comment: That I have no idea sorry

Comment: @Tyler Of course it's possible. Simple - probably not. Good idea - probably not.